# How can I make my css files asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous

I can async jss:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.async = true;
        po.src = 'http://www.gbilet.com/bundles/js?v=Yur37nohu3520qcbUHF9UVZYqsXFf5BzamwK0bJ0zjE1';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

How can i just like it cs ??

Comment: what's your challenge?

Comment: Exactly the same way (or using a library as Yep Nope.js which is usually helpful to asynchronously load any resource - think about polyfills you want to conditionally load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// create a link tag
var link = document.createElement( "link" );
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = "main.css";
```

And then call a async function that inserts this link tag.

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` tag supports the async attribute to perform async loading (otherwise all scripts will block the page rendering until they fully loaded)

The `<style>` tag  doesn't support the async attribute at all, but you can emulate it using the syntax below on each CSS stylesheet inclusion

```
<link rel="preload" href="mystyles.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```